# How to represent a new part of class in python?

Tags: python, class

For example say I had a class like this:

```
class Planet(object):
    def _init_(self, id = 0, name="", mass = 0)
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.mass = mass
```

Can I write the planet earth like this -

```
import(whatever)
name=earth
id=1
mass = 5.97219 × 1024 kg
```

or must planet earth be written in the same way the class does (sorry for my bad formatting, the code for each is combined into one block not separate ones)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `Planet` and initialize it:

```
earth = Planet()
earth.name = "earth"
earth.id = id
earth.mass = 5.97219 × 1024 kg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Planet(object):
    def _init_(self, id = 0, name="", mass = 0)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass

earth = Planet(id=1,name="Earth",mass=5.97219*1024)
```

Classes are great! Imagine you want your planet to be able to do something, possibly to other planets. How about this?

```
class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self,id=0,name="",mass=0,population=0)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.population = population
    def colonize(self,other,size = 1000):
        if not isinstance(other,Planet):
            raise TypeError("You can only colonize other celestial bodies!")
        if not isinstance(size,int):
            raise TypeError("You need a number of people to colonize with")
        self.population -= size
        other.population += size

mercury = Planet(1, "Mercury")
venus = Planet(2,"Venus")
earth = Planet(3,"Earth",5.97219*1024,7000000000)
mars = Planet(4,"Mars")

>>> earth.population
7000000000
>>> mars.population
0
>>> earth.colonize(mars)
>>> earth.population
6999999000
>>> mars.population
1000
```

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand... def colonize(self,other,size = 1000):
        if not isinstance(other,Planet):
            raise TypeError("You can only colonize other celestial bodies!")
        if not isinstance(size,int):
            raise TypeError("You need a number of people to colonize with")
        self.population -= size
        other.population += size

Comment: `self.foo` describes an attribute of an object. if `earth` is a `Planet`, then `earth.name == "Earth"` (assuming you set it so during instantiation, e.g. `earth = Planet(name="Earth")`. In this case, I added method to the class called `colonize`, that accepts another `Planet` and an optional `int` as parameters, then moves `size` population from the calling `Planet` to the other `Planet`. In other words, `earth.colonize(mars,2000)` moves 2000 `population` from `earth` to `mars`. The `isinstance` checks and the `raise` calls are just type checking -- it wouldn't make sense to colonize a string!

Comment: @user122083 so in other words, if `earth = Planet(name="Earth", population = 7000000000)` and `mars = Planet(name="Mars")`, then `earth.population` will be `7000000000`, `mars.population` will be `0`, but `earth.colonize(mars)` will move (by default) `1000` population from `earth` to `mars`.

Comment: Also, can a put a new instance of a class in a new file or must it be put into the same file as the description of the class?

Comment: @user122083 you can split your code into different `modules` by saving it in a separate file. For example if you wrote all your class definitions, saved them in `celestials.py`, you could put in your main program `import celestials`, then use `earth = celestials.Planet()` and `sun = celestials.Star()` etc

Comment: Two last questions (one for verification):                                            1. So in the file I write the overall class definition for planets and then the properties and behavior for each planet in the SAME file. Then I load this file into my new program and select a certain planet?                                                               2. Is this possible.  Say I had an option that allows planets to be combined into a solar system.  And that solar system designed freely by the user is ONE entity.  Would I have to make a class for solar system for this or can it just happen

Comment: @user122083 this is kind of off-topic. If you have a google account, add uo.asmith@gmail.com and we can chat there and I can illustrate a little better :)